# MutableLiveData is null in JUnitTest

Tags: android, testing, androidx, android-testing, android-livedata

I want to write a unit test. Therefore I need MutableLiveData. I started with a very basic test for setup but I cannot instantiate a MutableLiveData object. I is always null when I run the test. Do I have to mock anything? Any suggestions?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DefaultLiveDataTest {

    private static final int EXPECTED = 5;

    private final MutableLiveData<Integer> underTest = new MutableLiveData<>();


    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {

    underTest.setValue(EXPECTED); //underTest is Null
    assertEquals(underTest.getValue().intValue(), EXPECTED);

    }
}

java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:58)
at android.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:434)
at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:279)
at android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
at com.mypackage.DefaultLiveDataTest.test_that_live_data_has_default_value(DefaultLiveDataTest.java:22)
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.mypackage.title'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1'

annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.4.0'
implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.4.0'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the android.arch.core:core-testing dependency.

```
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
```

This allows you to use the InstantTaskExecutorRule in your test, which will get rid of the isMainThread call.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule.html

```
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

Comment: Note, that if you still used mockito 1.x, this will force you to update to mockito 2.19

Comment: for androidx what will be dependency?

Comment: For AndroidX it's currently `androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0`. Also note that the rule only seems to work with JUnit 4 but not with 5.

Comment: Yes, for Junit 5 you would just create your own Extension. If it's nowhere yet on Stackoverflow then feel free to create a question and I can add the implementation of my custom extension. @SoH
If you link the question here

Comment: @MichaelTroger heres a link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582063/unit-testing-livedata-observerforever-results-in-nullpointer-exception-with-juni

Comment: yeah make sure its public!

Answer (score 18):

Add an executor `InstantTaskExecutorRule()` as a member of the Test class

> A JUnit Test Rule that swaps the background executor used by the
> Architecture Components with a different one which executes each task
> synchronously. You can use this rule for your host side tests that use
> Architecture Components.

```
//@RunWith(JUnit4::class)   // For JUnit4
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)   // For JUnit5
class FilterViewModelTest {

    @Rule @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Test
    fun test() {
        //Here you don't ask if isMainThread
    }
}
```

### build.gradle(:mobile)

```
android {
    //...
    dependencies {
        //...
        testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

GL

[InstantTaskExecutorRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule)

Comment: This is the more up-to-date answer. Thank you.

Comment: I was missing  `@RunWith(JUnit4::class)` and no other answer anywhere on internet mentioned that. Thank you friend.

Comment: For junit5 replace `@RunWith(JUnit4::class)` on top of the class with `@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)`  and remove the val.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error and solved it by adding InstantTaskExecutorRule:

```
private lateinit var contactProfileViewModel: ContactProfileViewModel

private val getStatusesForContact: GetStatusesForContact = mockk(relaxed = true)
private val getStory: GetUserLastStory = mockk(relaxed = true)
private val successStatusesCaptor = slot<((List<StatusDomain>) -> Unit)>()
private val successStoryCaptor = slot<((List<StoryDomain>) -> Unit)>()

@get:Rule
val rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Before
fun setUp(){
    contactProfileViewModel = ContactProfileViewModel(getStatusesForContact, getStory)
}
```