# Unit testing LiveData observerForever results in NullPointer Exception with Junit5

Tags: android, junit, data-binding, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I am using Android databinding to listen to live data changes and I would like to observe changes on the viewmodel level (Rather then observing on fragment and then sending a callback to the viewmodel)
The `observerForever` is interesting as it serves the purpose for me. However when I run a test I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:461)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:222)
at com.bcgdv.ber.maha.login.ui.LoginViewModel.<init>(LoginViewModel.kt:43)
at com.bcgdv.ber.maha.login.ui.LoginViewModelTest.<init>(LoginViewModelTest.kt:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:443)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
```

My code is as follows in the viewmodel class:

```
val observerEmail: Observer<String> = Observer {
    setEmailError(it)
    checkLoginButton()
}
var email = MutableLiveData<String>()
init {
    email.observeForever(observerEmail)
}
```

Also to note is I am using Junit5.

```
@ExtendWith(InstantTaskExecutorExtension::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {
    val emailAddress = "xyz@xyz.com"
    val password = "password"
    val user: User = User("1", "xyz@xyz.com", "password")
val loginUsecase: LoginUseCase = mock {
    on { loginUser(emailAddress, password) } doReturn (Single.just(user))
}

private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel(
    loginUsecase,
    LoginCredentialsValidator(),
    Schedulers.trampoline(),
    Schedulers.trampoline()
)

@Test
fun should_return_user_as_null_initially() {
    whenever(loginUsecase.getUser()).thenReturn(null)
    loginViewModel.init()
    assertEquals(
        expected = null,
        actual = loginViewModel.obsEmail.get()
    )
}}
```

And this is the InstantTaskExecutorExtension.

```
class InstantTaskExecutorExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
    ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance()
            .setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
                override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()

                override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()

                override fun isMainThread(): Boolean = true
            })
}

override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
    ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MutableLiveData is null in JUnitTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840444/mutablelivedata-is-null-in-junittest)

Comment: @BhavikKasundra I tried it. I still get an error.

Comment: @SoH I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this.

Comment: I ended up not using the init. Also I am not using livedata. instead using observable fields and hooking them up with rxjava publish subjects

Comment: Can you double check, if your `@Test` annotation comes from the JUnit5 jupiter packages? That happened to me...

Answer (score 0):

In general it's recommended to use LiveData only for View Model <-> View communication, however I think the issue is:

```
private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel(
    ...
)
```

Because since this is a member variable it would be executed before the test and it's already implicitly executing `init()` since you call the constructor.
No need to call `init()` explicitly. I'd remove the `loginViewModel` member variable and instantiate it in the test function via the constructor:

```
@Test
fun should_return_user_as_null_initially() {
    ...
    LoginViewModel(
       ...
    )
    ...
}
```

Comment: Made changes to my answer. I was already using a task extension. Still get the same issue. I am using observeForever in the viewmodel itself. in the init method.