# Transformed LiveData's value is always null in unit testing even when observed, but works fine in the UI

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata, android-testing, mockk

I want to test a `LiveData`'s value. This `LiveData`'s value depends on another `LiveData` in the ViewModel. When I run the app, the UI is working as intended. However, when I create a unit test to test the dependent `LiveData`, the test always fails with an `AssertionError` saying that the value is always `null`.

I have the following `LiveData` in my ViewModel.

```
class MovieViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val state = movieRepository.getMoviesState()
    val errorLoading: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = Transformations.map(state) { it == State.ERROR }
    val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = Transformations.map(state) { it == State.LOADING }
    ...
}
```

The `LiveData` I want to test are `errorLoading` and `isLoading`. To do that, I use Mockk to mock objects and have the following code to test them both.

```
    @Test
    fun ensure_isLoading_is_true_when_state_is_loading() {
        ...
        every { movieRepository.getMoviesState() } returns MutableLiveData(State.LOADING)
        every { booleanObserver.onChanged(any()) } just runs
        viewmodel = MovieViewModel(movieRepository)
        verify { movieRepository.getMoviesState() }
        viewmodel.isLoading.observeForever(booleanObserver)
        verify { booleanObserver.onChanged(true) }
        assertEquals(true, viewmodel.isLoading.value)
        viewmodel.isLoading.removeObserver(booleanObserver)
    }
```

So far, the test can verify that `onChanged` on the mocked Observer is called and the value of the new change is also correct. However, when I want to access the value of the `LiveData` I want to test, it always returns null.

I am aware that the `LiveData` needs to be observed and I have made  a mock Observer to do that. However, the test still fails. Why does it always return null?

Comment: Did you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840444/mutablelivedata-is-null-in-junittest/49840604

Comment: @kolboc No, I didn't, but it seems like it's unrelated to my question.

Comment: Did you used this `InstantTaskExecutorRule()` ?

Comment: @hamid Yes, I did.

Comment: @Richard did you find any solution for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :

```
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = new 
InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

Comment: I have used that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discovered that the problem is with backing property.
When you use it with get() like this:

```
val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = Transformations.map(state) { it == State.LOADING }
```

then when calling `isLoading` you get a new (empty) LiveData instance.
Simply get rid of backing property and use it that way:

```
val _isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>
val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(state) { it == State.LOADING }
```